# Refraction without CubeMap

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to apply refraction on a Three.js experiment. All examples I found need a CubeMap to work. Is it possible to have refraction without it? Example, I want to create a sphere or a Circle in a Sprite and want that texture to use refraction of whatever content is on my Three.Scene.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean refraction or reflection?

Comment: Refraction, though I think they might work the same way...

Comment: Refraction and reflection are two quite different things: http://www.differencebetween.net/science/difference-between-reflection-and-refraction/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, however, my question is still unanswear :) http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_cubemap_balls_refraction uses several textures for the refraction. I just want one.

Comment: Either way, The only way I know how to accomplish either in Three.js is with a cube map. Though maybe this post could point you in the right direction. http://madebyevan.com/webgl-water/